# apt-get --force-yes: How to suppress further questions

Tags: apt

Take the `acroread` or `libpam-ldap` packages as examples.

Even when installed with `apt-get --force-yes` they still ask questions:

- `acroread` wants to know whether acrobat should be the standard PDF reader (how to assume yes?)
- `libpam-ldap` What's your LDAP-Servers URI, version, password, ...? (how to just assume anything, the `ldap.conf` will be overwritten by puppet anyway)

Is there a "for god's sake assume anything and stop nagging"-switch for `apt-get`?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try:

```
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
apt-get -y install package1 package2
```

Comment: Is `export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive` needed or the `y` option in `apt-get` is sufficient?

Answer (score 1):

Another solution: use `yes` command to blindly answer yes to all questions.

Apt is smart enough that this solution isn't recommended unless:

1. you know what you're doing, and
2. the `-y` and `--force-yes` options
   don't do what you want

In my case, I want to downgrade Nginx, and I don't care about the dependencies. For some reason `force-yes` didn't work, nor did the `DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive` environment variable.

Here's how to downgrade a package noninteractively:

```
yes | apt install nginx-common=1.4.6-1ubuntu3.3 nginx-full=1.4.6-1ubuntu3.3
```