# How to answer multiple yes/no when using apt-get in ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, apt

I am using "apt-get remove" to remove a package but during installation it asks me to enter yes/no twice for two different reason.

So I want my input to be yes for first question and no for second question.

Below is the code I am using with '-y' as option but it sets yes for all interaction.

```
apt-get --purge -y -f remove grub-pc
```

Can anyone tell me how to achieve what I have mentioned?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [apt-get --force-yes: How to suppress further questions](http://askubuntu.com/questions/308237/apt-get-force-yes-how-to-suppress-further-questions)

Comment: I can guess the first question, what is the second question? You can edit the question to add details

Comment: this is definitely not a duplicate of that post. OP knows how to force yes, and wants to apply an automatic yes and then no

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

`printf "yes\nno\n" | sudo apt-get ...`

Obviously, don't use `-y`, because you provide the answers you want using the piped output from `printf`.  You also need to know exactly how many answers you have to answer, and the right answer to give.